# TypeScript conditional generic based on constructor argument

Tags: typescript

I have a class like:

```
class Collection<ID extends string | number> {
    entries: ID[];

    constructor(private readonly useStringIds: boolean) {}

    getIds(): ID[] {
        return entries.map((entry) => entry.id);
    }

    handleResults(results: ObjectWithNumberId[]) {
        if (this.useStringIds) {
            this.entries = results.map((result) => ({
                ...result,
                id: result.id.toString(),
            }));
        } else {
            this.entries = results;
        }        
    }
}
```

where sometimes the `id` field will be left as is as a `number`, and sometimes I have to convert it.

However, I have to coordinate both the generic type and the argument passed into the constructor (`const c = new Collection<string>(true);`). Is there any way in TypeScript to just be able to pass in an argument to the class, and from there it knows which type the generic should correspond to automatically?

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that demonstrates your issue without introducing other problems you don't care about.  Right now that class has [a bunch of errors in it](https://tsplay.dev/m3qE3w) and apparently none of those errors are related to the question?  Please fix them so it's not a distraction.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way. It is significantly simpler when you want to directly use the generic as part of the constructor signature.

```
class Wrapper<Type extends string | number> {
  constructor(value: Type) {}
}

const wrapper = new Wrapper("test") // typeof Wrapper<string>
```

But we can make it work for your case too, just make sure to understand the concept above. As we will rely on it. We will also use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).

```
class Collection<UseStringIds extends boolean, ID extends UseStringIds extends true ? string : number = UseStringIds extends true ? string : number> {
  constructor(useStringIds: UseStringIds) {}
  ...
}

const myInstance = new Collection(false) // typeof Collection<true, number>
type myInstanceType = Collection<true> // typeof Collection<true, string>
```

Lets deconstruct the admittedly long Generic deceleration:

`UseStringIds extends boolean` gets inferred as you wanted when instantiating.

`UseStringIds extends true ? string : number` this term is dependent on `UseStringIds`. When `UseStringIds` is true it resolves to string otherwise number. We set this to ID via: `ID extends ...`. Then we copy the same term which it must extend and set it to the default type as well. So that when using it as a type we only have to write `Collection<true>`.